# Parsing text from HTML tags

Tags: html, perl, parsing, tags

I'm using a Perl program to extract text from a batch of .htm files and storing all unique ten-word sequences as keys in a hash (the end result is hash with each unique ten-word sequence as a key and the number of times that sequence appears in all files as the value).

My problem is the code continues to extract HTML tags along with the text, despite several attempts to get rid of the HTML using modules such as [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser).  The code below produces no error messages, but it doesn't get rid of the HTML tags either.  Any insights?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyParser;
use base qw(HTML::Parser);
my $p = HTML::Parser->new;

my $path = "U:/Perl/risk disclosures";
chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";

# This program counts the total number of unique six-grams in a 10-K and enumerates the frequency     of each one.
# Starting off computing a simple word count for each word in the 10-K.

my @sequence;
my %sequences;
my $fh;

# Here creating an array of ten-grams.
my @files = <*.htm>;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open( IFILE, $file );
    while (<IFILE>) {
        $p->parse($_);
        for (split) {
            push @sequence, $_;
            if ( @sequence >= 10 ) {
                shift @sequence until @sequence == 10;
                ++$sequences{"@sequence"};
            }
        }
    }
}
close(IFILE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to extract all the text from the HTML document:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

my $text = $dom->all_text();

print $text;

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World<title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header One</h1>
<p>Paragraph One, word one two three four five six seven eight nine <b>TEN</b> eleven
twelve thirteen fourteen.</p>
<p>Paragraph two, word one two three four five six seven eight nine <b>TEN</b> eleven
twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World Header One Paragraph One, word one two three four five six seven eight nine TEN eleven twelve thirteen fourteen. Paragraph two, word one two three four five six seven eight nine TEN eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
```

And if you just want the text in the body, use:

```
my $text = $dom->at('body')->all_text();
```

#### Addendum about loading the file's contents

`Mojo::DOM` accepts a string of data.  It currently does not have an interface for being passed a file handle.

One must therefore load the file's contents themselves before instantiating a dom object:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# This program counts the total number of unique six-grams in a 10-K and enumerates the frequency of each one.
# Starting off computing a simple word count for each word in the 10-K.

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $path = "U:/Perl/risk disclosures";
chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";

for my $file (<*.htm>) {
    my $data = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $file;
        local $/;    # Slurp mode
        <$fh>;
    };
    my $dom  = Mojo::DOM->new($data);
    my $text = $dom->all_text();

    # Further processing from here
    ...;
}
```

Comment: My first attempt with this results in a "Can't locate Mojo/DOM.pm in @INC..." error message.  I'll keep working on that--in the meantime, do I need to open the original file prior to using the "my $dom = Mojo" line?  Else where in the above code would you put this?

Comment: First, you'll need to install [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us/).  Second, you'll need to load each file contents before creating a `Mojo::DOM` object like I've demonstrated here.  Everything else can match what you're already doing in your script.

Comment: I couldn't get the commands as written to parse the HTML tags from my files in my program (Mojo lines inserted after the while loop).  I just ended up with unparsed output as before. Modifying those two lines to be: " my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($fh); my $text = $dom->all_text();" gives no errors, but the resulting output becomes "GLOB(0x36ba34)" repeated several times. Do you see anything obviously wrong with this code?

Comment: `Mojo::DOM` accepts a string of data to parse, not a file handle.  You must load the file's content yourself.  I've added an addendum to demonstrate.

Comment: Working on this more this morning, Miller's answer was even more helpful than I first realized.  The local (slurp) mode fixed another problem I was having where all the data wasn't being read in correctly and the parsing wasn't working.  Now all the data comes through and the text is correctly extracted from the HTML tags.

Comment: I'm curious, in the example above, how does one extract a hash with the headings and associated paragraph text.  So h1A->h2A->text, H1B->text etc.